# what will be happen when using more than one form tag in ASP.Net application?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

what will be happen when using more than one form tag in web application?

I am using form tag in master page and alos in child page. but it shows error.

Comment: It's 2020. It's been **12 years** since ASP.NET WebForms was rendered obsolete by ASP.NET MVC back in 2008. Why are you still using it?

Comment: From the screen shot it looks like you already answered your own question...

Comment: Why bother having `<form runat="server">` in your child pages anyways? Just put it in your master page and move on (preferably to something not Web Forms based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what will be happen when using more than one form tag in web application?

You can use as many `<form>` elements in a page as you want (though they cannot be nested). But, as you've noticed, **you can only have only one `<form runat="server">` element in each *composed* `Page` instance** (that is, the control layout of all composed `.master` pages around the current `.aspx` page and any child `Control` or `.ascx` UserControl instances).

This is because ASP.NET WebForms is built around the assumption that each user's action (a button click, a `<select>` selection change, a radio-button click, etc) would trigger a "whole page post-back" which would reload the entire page in a `POST` response, which (combined with `__VIEWSTATE`) would bring a model similar to VB6 desktop forms to to the web.

...but this was back in 2001 when ASP.NET WebForms was released, and since then everyone has realized that WebForms' "postback" model was a huge mistake and literally broke the web (because it breaks the back-button, it broke the refresh button, it broke the semantics of HTTP methods, and it would transform the web from being a scalable and stateless system into being a horrible stateful system with no real benefits to anyone other than a slightly shallower initial learning-curve for [a fraction of software developers who never left their Visual Basic comfort zone](https://blog.codinghorror.com/mort-elvis-einstein-and-you/)).

In short: Stop using ASP.NET WebForms and migrate to ASP.NET MVC as soon as you're able to.